# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream with static website

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

My goal is to have 2 docker containers:

- nginx container (based on nginx:latest) to work as reverse proxy
- container with static website (based on nginx:alpine)

Later I will add 1+ .net core backend services (not important for now). Currently when I try to access my webserver using public ip address, I get 502 Bad gateway. Here is my current configuration:

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: reverse_proxy
    depends_on:
      - static-website
    volumes:
      - ./reverse_proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
  static-website:
    image: sm-static-website
    build:
      context: ./website
    container_name: sm_static_website
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

nginx.conf for reverse-proxy:

```
worker_processes auto;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;

            server_name x.x.x.x; # my_public_ip

            location / {
                    proxy_pass              http://sm_static_website:8080;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile for static website:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /html
COPY . /var/www/html
EXPOSE 8080
```

From my website container I can see that nginx is running / listening on 80:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:41389        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTE       1/nginx: master pro
```

From my server I can see that both remote_proxy and website containers are listening to 80/8080, respectively:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13936/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13797/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      13942/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      13804/docker-proxy
```

ps -aux on server returns:

```
root       13936  0.0  0.0 1075140 3580 ?        Sl   00:24   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 80 -container-ip 172.18.0.3 -container-port 80
root       13797  0.0  0.0 1148872 3624 ?        Sl   00:24   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 80
```

Website container's log shows no error, worker processes are running. However, reverse proxy log shows:

```
2022/05/20 01:20:29 [error] 31#31: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: x.x.x.x, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.2:8080/", host: "x.x.x.x"
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? If I remove volumes: line from docker-compose.yml, then I get the default nginx page from the reverse-proxy container. This indicates that it is listening properly, accepting the request, but does not redirect it to website container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `port` directive in docker-compose defines which port is exposed to the outside. Your reverse proxy container can access the services in inside the `static-website` directly when they are linked together, so you don't use the exposed port here.

Since your website inside the container `static-website` is listening on port 80 you need to use that instead of the exposed ports.

First you need to link the containers together, to do that you add to the `reverse-proxy` block:

```yaml
links:
  - static-website
```

Your `proxy_pass` directive should be:

```
proxy_pass              http://sm_static_website;
```

If you don't want to actually expose the `static-website` container to the outside you can remove the `ports` directive there.

So the `docker-compose.yml` should look like this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: reverse_proxy
    depends_on:
      - static-website
    volumes:
      - ./reverse_proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - sm_static_website
  static-website:
    image: sm-static-website
    build:
      context: ./website
    container_name: sm_static_website
```

<sub>TBH: I never found it useful to use the `container_name` directive, I'm not sure if you have to use the defined container_name `sm_static_website` or just `static-website` in the `links` and in the `proxy_pass` directives. If you leave it out it would be just `static-website`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Gerald, changing to port 80 worked. First time dealing with linux and coker, so that is why this newbie question. P.S. Links uses <service-name>, so